# Javascript code to switch image doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, image, chromium

I'm a Javascript newb and I'm working on some buttons which 'flash' when clicked.  When an icon is clicked, my Javascript code swaps out one icon image and replaces it with an illuminated icon.  This works fine in FF and IE9, but not Chrome.

Here's the code:

```
<html>

<head>
<script Language="Javascript">
function set0()
{
    document.location="cgi-bin/set0.cgi";
    document.getElementById("l").src="/img/leftglow.jpg";

}
function set1()
{
    document.location="cgi-bin/set1.cgi";
    document.getElementById("r").src="/img/rightglow.jpg";
}
function set01()
{
    document.location="/cgi-bin/set01.cgi";
    document.getElementById("f").src="/img/forwardglow.jpg";
}
function clear01(event)
{
    document.location="cgi-bin/clear01.cgi";

    document.getElementById("r").src="/img/right.jpg";
    document.getElementById("l").src="/img/left.jpg";
    document.getElementById("f").src="/img/forward.jpg";
    if(event.type=="mousedown")
    {
        document.getElementById("s").src="/img/stopglow.jpg";
    }
    if(event.type=="mouseup")
    {
        document.getElementById("s").src="/img/stop.jpg";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>Raspberry Pi GPIO</h1>

    <img src="/img/forward.jpg" id="f" onmousedown="set01()" onmouseup="clear01(event)">
<br>
    <img src="/img/left.jpg" id="l" onmousedown="set0()" onmouseup="clear01(event)">
    <img src="/img/right.jpg" id="r" onmousedown="set1()" onmouseup="clear01(event)">
<br>
    <img src="/img/stop.jpg" id="s" onmousedown="clear01(event)" onmouseup="clear01(event)">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CGI scripts don't print any HTML.  They just set some GPIO pins and print a 204 No Content header so that the browser stays on the current page.  This only partially works in Chrome - the CGI scripts get executed, and the original icon dissappears and reappears, but the illuminated icon isn't displayed.  Does anyone know what I need to do to make this work in Chrome?

Comment: Setting the location would redirect the page. How would setting an image after that make any difference?

Comment: Each of the CGI scripts prints a 204 header so the browser doesn't leave the current page.  This works in FF and IE, and in Chrome the code in clear01 works, it's just the setxx functions that don't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting the HTML5 doctype (Change add in <!DOCTYPE html> at the top), also do you get any errors show in the development console? (F12)